# Magento get All tree Categories

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category, category-tree

I want to get all categories in store. so if set any category option **not including in navigation menu** the category not showing in list tree.

So My question: **how i can get all tree categories both including and not including in navigation menu**.

I've use below function :

```
public function getStoreCategories()
{
  $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
  return $helper->getStoreCategories();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all categories in magento 1.9.2.4 -

```
<?php  $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category'); $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories(); if (count($_categories) > 0){
    foreach($_categories as $_category){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($_subcategories) > 0){
            echo $_category->getName();
            echo $_category->getId();      
            foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){
                 echo $_subcategory->getName();
                 echo $_subcategory->getId();
            }
        }
    } } ?>
```

To get a single category we should use -

```
<?php 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4); //4 = categoryID
$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
if (count($subcategories) > 0){
    echo $category->getName();
    foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
         echo $subcategory->getName();
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps :)